# simple midi file writer in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, hex, midi

I'm writing a program in Objective C to generate a MIDI file. As a test, I'm asking it to write a file which plays one note and stops it a delta tick afterwards.

But I'm trying to open it with Logic and Sibelius, and they both say that the file is corrupted.

Here's the hex readout of the file..

```
4D 54 68 64   00 00 00 06   00 01 00 01   00 40   - MThd header

4D 54 72 6B   00 00 00 0D      - MTrk - with length of 13 as 32bit hex [00 00 00 0D]


81 00   90 48 64   82 00    80 48 64  - the track
delta    noteOn    delta    noteOff 


FF 2F 00                       - end of file
```

And here's my routines to write the delta time, and write the note -

```
- (void) appendNote:(int)note state:(BOOL)on isMelody:(BOOL)melodyNote{           // generate a MIDI note and add it to the 'track' NSData object
char c[3];

if( on ){
    c[0] = 0x90;
    c[2] = volume;
} else {
    c[0] = 0x80;
    c[2] = lastVolume;
}
c[1] = note;

[track appendBytes:&c length:3];
```

}

```
- (void) writeVarTime:(int)value{                       // generate a MIDI delta time and add it to the 'track' NSData object
char c[2];
if( value < 128 ){
    c[0] = value;
    [track appendBytes:&c length:1];
} else {
    c[0] = value/128 | 0x80;
    c[1] = value % 128;
    [track appendBytes:&c length:2];
}
```

}

are there any clever MIDI gurus out there who can tell what's wrong with this MIDI file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delta time of the EOF event is missing.

Comment: Thanks! That's got it.. Now I'm trying to figure out how to create a 32-bit hex value for the MTRK length, it's a bit of a struggle..